# Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol with finite field GF(2^5)

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, finite-field

In a Diffie-Hellman key exchange protocol, the system parameters are given as
follows: finite field $GF(2^5)$ defined with irreducible polynomial $f(x) = x^5 + x^2 + 1$ and
primitive element $\alpha= x$ in the field.

Suppose that Alice selected random number $a = 5$ and Bob selected $b = 6$, show the steps
performed by Alice and Bob to obtain their shared key. What is the key?

**For Alice:**

$α^a = α^5 = x^5 = (x^2 + 1)$

**For Bob:**

$α^b = α^6 = x*x^5 = x(x^2 + 1) = x^3 + x$

**Shared Key For Alice:**

$α^{ab} = (x^2 + 1)^b = (x^2 + 1)^6\ldots$

**Shared Key For Bob:**

$α^{ab} = (x^3 + x)^a = (x^3 + x)^5\ldots$

The answer is $x^4 + x$ but I'm not sure how to simplify to this answer from both sides either Alice or Bob which should have the same shared Key

Comment: $(x^2+1)^6={({(x^2+1)}^2)}^3={({(x^2+1)}^2)}^2\times {(x^2+1)}^2=...$.

Comment: No this isn't homework I am studying for a final exam and these were additional problems I found in my textbook because I wanted to study extra. He didn't ask them in class but this professor is known to ask difficult problems that were not covered I just wanted to be extra prepared I can try to answer it i'm just a little stuck about how the reductions work I just don't get how you'd know to do these steps and why? I came up with a solution (60 lines so it seems like luck) and really I wouldn't have known when to stop at x^4 + x I don't get why that is the answer and not one of my previous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three words [Finite Field Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic). The elements of a Finite Field (Galois field) can be represented by a [polynomial](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70235/18298), like in this case. We prefer it since it gave us good computing properties.

$\rm GF(2^5)$ is a binary field extension with the base field 2, the binary field. To construct this field we need an irreducible binary polynomial <sup>[*]</sup> of degree  5<sup>[‡]</sup>. In your case it is $f(x)=x^5+x^2+1$. The field can be [constructed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Explicit_construction) by $\operatorname{GF} (2)[x]/f(x)$<sup>[+]</sup>. An [irreducible binary polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) with degree 5 need not be unique, there is only 6 possibilities for constructing $\operatorname{GF}(2^5)$ <sup>[#]</sup>.

1. $f(x)=1+x^2+x^5$,
2. $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^5$,
3. $f(x)=1+x^3+x^5$,
4. $f(x)=1+x+x^3+x^4+x^5$,
5. $f(x)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$, and
6. $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^4+x^5$

For the binary field extension and we prefer the ones with small degree monomials and with fewer monomials. So, $f(x)=1+x^2+x^5$  is a good choice.

The addition is polynomial addition with the coefficients are reduced to the base field. Multiplication is a bit tricky, we need modulo reduction with the irreducible polynomial. In your case, whenever you see $x^5$ replace it with $x^2+1$. In this [website](http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/galois3.pl?p=6&C=1&D=1&A=1), you can see the table for addition and multiplication. For small cases, generating the table and hardcoding it in a table can be helpful, however, be aware of the cache attacks.

One way is multiplying all at once then reduce
\begin{align}
(x^2 + 1)^6 &= x^{12} + 6 x^{10} + 15 x^8 + 20 x^6 + 15 x^4 + 6 x^2 + 1 \\
            &= x^{12} + x^8 + 15 x^4 + 1 \\
     \vdots &= \vdots\\
\end{align}

This is not the preferred method since it can scale too much, especially for large finite fields. The better method is the multiply-and-reduce paradigm as below.

\begin{align}
(x^2 + 1)^6 &= ((x^2 + 1)^2)^2 (x^2 + 1)^2  &&,\text{expand one level } \\
            &= (x^4 + \color{red}{2} x^2 + 1)^2 (x^4 + \color{red}{2} x^2 + 1) && , \color{red}{2=0} \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_2\\
            &= (x^4 + 1)^2 (x^4 + 1) &&,\text{work on left} \\
            &= (x^8 + \color{red}{2}x + 1) (x^4 + 1)  && , \color{red}{2=0} \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_2\\
            &= (x^8 + 1) (x^4 + 1)  && , \text{use } x^5 = x^2+1\\ 
            &= ((x^5)x^3 + 1) (x^4 + 1) \\
            &= ((x^2+1)x^3 + 1) (x^4 + 1) \\
            &= (x^5 + x^3 + 1 ) (x^4 + 1)&& , \text{use } x^5 = x^2+1\\
            &= (x^2+ \color{red}{1} + x^3 + \color{red}{1} ) (x^4 + 1)&& , \color{red}{2=0} \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_2\\
            &= (x^3 + x^2 ) (x^4 + 1) &&, \text{multiply}\\
            &= x^7 + x^6 + x^3 + x^2  &&,\text{use } x^5 = x^2+1\\
            &= (x^2+1)x^2 + (x^2+1)x + x^3 + x^2 &&,\text{expand } \\
            &= x^4 + \color{red}{2} x^3 + \color{red}{2} x^2 + x &&,\text{use }\color{red}{2=0} \text{ in } \mathbb{F}_2\\
            &= x^4+ x &&  
\end{align}

And, for the other equation, you can see their equality by; $$(x^3+x)^5=x^5(x^2+1)^5=(x^2+1)(x^2+1)^5=(x^2+1)^6$$

We, actually, use **bit vector** to process the binary polynomials:

$ (x^2+1)= [00101]$, we can represent with 5 bits since the finite field $GF(2^5)$.

Whenever we see, 1 out of size 5 we reduce it.

- $ (x^5)= [1|00000] = [00101]$, the reduction is shift and x-or. We can say, replace the 1 with position 5 with $[0|00101]$ and x-or. Similarly, we can write formulas for
- $x^6 = (x^5)x = [01001]$ and
- $x^7 = (x^5)x^2 = [10100]$, and so on. In your case 6 should be enough if you multiply one by one.

\begin{align}
[00101]^6 &= [00101]\cdot [00101]\cdot [00101]^4 \\
          &= [10001]\cdot [00101]\cdot [00101]^3 \\ 
          &= [10|10001]\cdot [00101]^3 \tag{use $x^6$}\\
          &= [11000] \cdot [00101] \cdot [00101]^2\\  
          &= [11|11000] \cdot [00101]^2\\ 
   \vdots &= \vdots 
\end{align}

---

<sup>[*]</sup> A polynomial is said to be irreducible if it cannot be factored into nontrivial polynomials over the same field. ([Wolfram defn.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrreduciblePolynomial.html))

<sup>[#]</sup> The list is taken from Wolfram, too.

<sup>[‡]</sup> There is a sequence on the number of binary polynomials on the degree; [OEIS A059912](http://oeis.org/A059912)

<sup>[+]</sup> In the general case; for for a prime $p$ an the prime power $q=p^n$, $n \in \mathbb Z^+$, with the irreducible polynomial $f$ of
degree $n$, the quotient ring

$${\operatorname{GF}}(q)={\operatorname{GF}}(p)[X]/(f(x))$$
of the polynomial ring $\operatorname{GF}(p)[X]$ by the ideal generated by $f(x)$ is a finite field of order $q$.

Comment: Note, I did most of this without a computer, so there may be calculation errors.

Comment: Maybe you could point out, that for larger numbers, square and multiply (as in your first calculation) scales much, much better than the entire expansion in one step.

Comment: That helped a lot I think the =((x^2+1)^3+1)(x^4+1) line has an error I think rather it should be (x^2+1)*x^3

Comment: @user3371137 corrected

Comment: @tylo better now?

Comment: Don't you mean $q=p^n$ so GF(q)=GF(p^n)=GF(p)[x]/irredn(x)?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeap, thanks for the notice, corrected.