# Find Consecutive X-Coordinate algorithm

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves

The question is as follows: Is there an algorithm to calculate a $(x,y)$ pair which is consecutive to an existing $x$-Coordinate on an elliptic curve?

Background Information for the curve:

Known Values: Prime Curve ($p$), Prime Multiplier ($N$), Trace ($P-N$), Curve is Half. Multipliers $(M_1 + M_2) = N$, $y$ Coordinates + Inverse $Y$ Coordinate = $P$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Update: An algorithm to calculate a $(x,y)$ pair and integer multiplier which is consecutive to an existing $x$-coordinate on the curve.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P = (x,y)$ be a point on the curve $E$ with the $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ with [Weierstrass equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions) over the [prime field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Subfields_and_prime_fields) $\operatorname{GF}(p)$<sup>1</sup>, i.e. it satisfies the curve equation.

The consecutive $x$-coordinate point can be found with the below algorithm.

```
for i from 1 to number_of_poinst_on_the_curve
    temp = x + i mod p
    if  (temp, y) satisfies the curve equation
       return (temp,y')   
    else
       continue
throw no_consecutive_element
```

- The $\bmod p$ is necessary since we don't want our $x$ has value out of the possible space.
- $y'$ is one of the two possible solitons to the $y^2$, except when $y=\mathcal{O}$, the point at the infinity. The educative details of finding the square root in modular arithmetic can be found on Fgrieu's latest answer;

  [Is it possible to compute the y-coordinate of a point on SECP256K1, given only the x-coordinate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/82031/18298)
- The algorithm will terminate since the EC has a finite number of points. The number of points can be

  - limited by Hasse's Theorem: $N - (q+1)| \le 2 \sqrt{q}$ over finite field with $q$ elements.
  - Or, exactly found by [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm), In the paper [Counting Points on Elliptic Curves over Finite Fields](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/%7Eschoof/ctg.pdf), published in 1985,
  - Or, the improved version [Schoof–Elkies–Atkin algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> This is used to simplify the algorithm. EC doesn't need to be defined over a prime finite field. In Cryptography, we use the general case of Finite Fields $\operatorname{GF}(q=p^m), m \in \mathbb{Z}, m\geq 1$. Expect the prime field, the other fields have [different representation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70229/18298) for the elements.</sub>

---

For $y^2 = x^3 + x^2 + x$ over $GF(131)$

[image]

```
E = EllipticCurve(GF(131),[0,1,0,1,0])

P=E.lift_x(0) #lift can throw an error if there is no point with the given input
              #tested before that there is a point with x=0

plotE = E.plot()

for t in srange(1,129):
    try:
        R =  E.lift_x(t)
        plotE += line([P.xy(),R.xy()],color='red')
        P = R
    except ValueError:  
        pass
plotE
```

**update**

Though I don't see the direct effect on Cryptography, there are academic works on this;

- [Integral Points in Arithmetic Progression on $y^2=x(x^2-n^2)$](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82695033.pdf), by Bremner, Silverman, and Tzanakis, 2000.