# On the hardness of addition when the elements of a field is represented by the powers of generator and possible any existant scheme

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field

We can represent elements of a finite field $F$ in various ways [polynomial basis and normal basis](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/70229/18298). There is one other; generator-based representation and this is based on the fact that the multiplicative group of a finite field ($F^*$) is cyclic so there is a generator of this cyclic group, call $g$ and we write $\langle g \rangle = F^*$. Now every element of $F^*$ can be written as powers of the generator as $x = g^i \in F$ for some positive integer $i$. The identity is $g^0$. In this way, the multiplication is easy

$$\text{let } a,b\in F, \text{ and } a = g^x, b = g^y \text{ then } a\cdot b = g^{x+y}.$$ The bonus is the fact that the discrete log is easy since we tack the elements by the generator's power but the addition seems hard. $$a +b = g^x + g^y = g^z, \quad z =?$$ Questions;

1. How hard the addition?
2. Are there any cryptographic scheme that uses this hardness?

Answer (score 1):

The term used for the function $Z(\cdot)$ defined by
$$
g^{x}+g^{y}=g^{x}(1+g^{y-x})=g^x g^{Z(y-x)},
$$
in coding theory literature is *Zech's logarithm*. So for your formulation $$z=x+Z(y-x)=y+Z(x-y).$$
It is no more than the DL of $(1+g^{x-y})$ and is believed to be as hard as DL.

In coding theory it is normally considered for even characteristic groups $G=GF(2^m)^\ast$ in which case it is actually just the DL composed with a permutation $\pi$ of order 2 in the additive exponent group $\mathbb{Z}_{2^m-1}.$

I seem to recall Odlyzko mentioning it in a survey on DL in early 1990's. In any case, I don't know of it being directly used in cryptographic schemes, but others might.