# Doubt on elliptic curve over a finite field and binary representation

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field

I'm a programmer, i.e. agnostic to the mathemathics behind most of cryptographic scheme, but I'm trying to remediate. I'm writing this premise for any possible error or imprecision that I probably put in this question.

However, I'm studying Elliptic Curve and I got to *Elliptic Curves over Finite fields* topic. For what I understood an elliptic over a finite field $F$ are the points that fulfill the Weierstrass equation where coefficients and coordinates belongs to $F$.

So far I always thought of F as the integer modulo $p$ (with $p$ prime). Point addition, doubling must be thus performed modulo p and all the points that pop out along with the point at infinity form a cyclic group. Ok, I got this.

Now problems begin: reading some handouts that a professor of mine gave to me, I read two things that I couldn't figure out.

First, they say that the order of a finite field is always a prime power (and such a power is named *extension degree* that he denotes with $m$): of course I trust this result but I couldn't figure out a field of order, say, $4$, $8$, $9$ or $16$. What are examples of such fields?

Secondly, if $p=2$, $m>1$ and $q=p^m$ (binary field), they say that (I'm citing):

> The elements of the a binary field of order $q=2^m$ cannot be represented as integers modulo $2^m$. A convenient way to represent them is by means of binary polynomials of degree less than m.

Why can't they be represented as integers modulo $2^m$? Any answers and/or reference is appreciated.

Comment: There are prime field-based curves, that is $F_p$ What you are asking is the finite field question. This [might](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70235/18298) help. The hint is that $F_{p^m}$ is considered as a vector space over $F_p$ with $m$ dimension. Could your share your slides?

Comment: The wikipedia article has an explicit example of a/the finite field with 4 elements: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#Non-prime_fields

Comment: Welcome to Crypto Stack Exchange. I've added some paragraph breaks and math formatting to your question to make it easier readable – please check the changes, and feel free to roll back, or edit again if I made something wrong.

Answer (score 6):

> I couldn't figure out a field of order, say, 4, 8, 9 or 16. What are examples of such fields?

Let's do that with $8=2^3$.

- Elements of that field $\mathbb F_{2^3}$ will be assimilated to $3$-bit quantities, that is the set $\{\mathtt0,\mathtt1\}^3$, or equivalently polynomials of degree less than $3$ with binary coefficients, where e.g. $\mathtt{110}$ is the polynomial $x^2+x$, and $\mathtt{101}$ is the polynomial $x^2+1$.
- Our addition is bitwise exclusive-OR, or equivalently addition of polynomials, so that $\mathtt{110}\oplus\mathtt{101}=\mathtt{011}$, or equivalently $(x^2+x)+(x^2+1)=x+1$.
- For our multiplication we choose an [irreducible_polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_polynomial) $P(x)$ of degree $3$ with binary coefficients (among two such polynomials, see this [list of irreducible polynomials over GF(2) up to degree 11](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-irredpoly.txt)), e.g. $P(x)=x^3+x+1$; and we define multiplication as polynomial multiplication followed by reduction modulo $P(x)$. This simply tells that when in the product we get a term of degree $d\ge3$, we can get rid of it by adding the polynomial $x^{d-3}\,P(x)\ =\ x^d+x^{d-2}+x^{d-3}$. So for example
  $$\begin{array}{lll}(x^2+x)\,(x^2+1)&=(x^2+x)\,x^2+(x^2+x)\\
  &=x^4+x^3+x^2+x\\
  &\equiv(x^4+x^3+x^2+x)+(x^4+x^2+x)&\pmod{x^3+x+1}\\
  &\equiv x^3&\pmod{x^3+x+1}\\
  &\equiv x^3+(x^3+x+1)&\pmod{x^3+x+1}\\
  &\equiv x+1&\pmod{x^3+x+1}\\
  \end{array}$$
  thus $\mathtt{110}\otimes\mathtt{101}=\mathtt{011}$.

The full multiplication table goes
$$\begin{array}{c|cccccccc}
\otimes     &\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{111}\\
\hline
\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{000}\\
\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{111}\\
\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{101}\\
\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{010}\\
\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{001}\\
\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{110}\\
\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{011}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{100}\\
\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{000}&\mathtt{111}&\mathtt{101}&\mathtt{010}&\mathtt{001}&\mathtt{110}&\mathtt{100}&\mathtt{011}\\
\end{array}$$
The neutral for $\otimes$ is $\mathtt{001}$ that is the polynomial $1$. The [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) and other commutative [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) properties follow from that for polynomials.

> The elements of the a binary field of order $q=2^m$ cannot be represented as integers modulo $2^m$.

Actually it's OK to represent them as integers, and even convenient in some computer languages (perhaps our $\oplus$ is just the bitwise-XOR operator `^`). But when $m>1$, addition and multiplication modulo $q=2^m$ give the [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) $\mathbb Z_q$, which is essentially useless to build the [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)) $\mathbb F_q$, for $\mathbb Z_q$'s addition and multiplication bear no relation with $\mathbb F_q$'s $\oplus$ and $\otimes$.

> A convenient way to represent elements of the a binary field of order $q=2^m$ is by means of binary polynomials of degree less than $m$.

Indeed. That's what we did above.

---

Following [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/191605)

> If $m=1$ then coordinates over elliptic curve are just scalars, whereas if $m>1$ then a coordinate is in its turn a "set of coordinate".

Yes, that's a useful way of seeing it. An element of the field $\mathbb F_{p^k}$ is most naturally expressed as $k$ "coordinates" each in $\{0,1\ldots,p-1\}$ when devising a general computer implementation of arithmetic in $\mathbb F_{p^k}$. The usual mathematical statement of the same thing is that such element is a polynomial of degree less than $k$, with coefficients in $\mathbb F_p==\mathbb Z_p$.

In the first part of the answer I have specialized to $p=2$, since the question mentioned *binary* in the title, but we can do the same for any prime $p$, and that makes polynomial notation shine: it implies the definition of addition, and of multiplication with the help of an irreducible polynomial.

Comment: Ok, you've been clear but just to be sure can you confirm the following? If *m=1* then coordinates over elliptic curve are just scalars whereas if *m>1* then a coordinate is in its turn a "set of coordinate" (in your example belonging to *{0,1}^3*).
And about the integer representation: what are you trying to tell me is that it is not convenient to represent an element of a F when *m>1* because in that case I would have, for example, 110 XOR 111 = 101 becoming 6 XOR 7 = 5 that may result meaningless?

Comment: @user1108 "convenience" is relative. What the author meant here is that the "natural" ($+$ and $·$) operations on the integers modulo $p^m$ are not giving a field (they are a ring, but you have divisors of 0, so division is not unique), but the "normal" operations on polynomials modulo an irreducible polynomial to form a field (and up to isomorphism the only field of order $p^m$), so we don't need to define special operations here. XOR on integers mod $2^m$ is convenient enough, the multiplication is a bit more complicated to implement.

Comment: @user1108: I tried to clarify in updated answer (and changed primitive to irreducible as it should be).

Comment: Thanks  @fgrieu. Now it's much clearer to me. I still would have a lot of questions about this marvelous branch of mathematics so I ask one more thing: can you suggest me a set (forgive me the joke) of reference (textbook and/or online handouts) that gather elliptic curves theory for cryptographer? I would enjoy them.

Comment: Thanks also to @PaŭloEbermann (apparently I cannot cite more than a user in a comment)

Comment: @user1108: for a free, online, concise reference on finite fields in a crypto context, I use the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) especially [section 2.6](https://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap2.pdf#page=34). The HAC does not cover Elliptic Curves though. With the same authors, but not free, there's [Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387952734); it has excellent [free pages](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9780387952734-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-110359-p8685189) on finite field arithmetic.

Comment: @user1108: For ECC, I often use [SECG](https://www.secg.org/), esp. [SEC 1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf) and  [SEC 2](https://www.secg.org/sec2-v2.pdf).

Comment: @fgrieu I really thank you. They look great. Those will be my next book :)

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a problem within abstract algebra rather than a problem within elliptic curves.

Integer modulo primepower $p^k$ would contain a zero divisor for k>1. Therefore, $\mathbb{Z}/p^k$ cannot be a field because you can't find, say, the multiplicative inverse of $p$. You could always consider $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ as $\mathbb{F_p}[x]/f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is some irreducible polynomial of degree $k$. Furthermore, whichever $f(x)$ you chose, they are always isomorphic.

There are many such polynomials. Exactly how many? Since $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ have order $p^k$ but they could possibly falls into lower extension degree. Write the prime factorization $k=\ell_1^{e_1}\dots \ell_r^{e_r}$. Say $c_d$ be the number of degree-d monic irreducible polynomial. Then we have
$$
p^k-p=\#\mathbb{F}_{p^k}\setminus\bigcup_{d|k}\mathbb{F_{p^d}}=\sum_{d|k}d\cdot c_d
$$
Using Mobius inversion, we easily obtain
$$
k\cdot c_k=\sum_{d|k}\mu(d) (p^{k/d}-p).
$$
You could therefore randomly pick one polynomial and then use algorithms such as Berlekamp's or Cantor-Zassenhaus to check that it is irreducible and resample if otherwise.